# Connect from Mac to windows for Asp.net core APIs locally

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am developing a cross platform app through Asp. Net Zero. My API server is running on Windows machine and I am trying to consume API on Mac. Both windows and Mac are on same wifi network.

I checked other posts and changed `applicationUrl` like

`"https://0.0.0.0:44301/;https://192.168.x.x:44301;http://windowsComputerName:5000/"`

Its not connecting.

Even `ping 192.168.x.x` gets timed out.

Is there any other network setting I should be changing to let Mac consume REST API?

Comment: is your server setup to accept remote connections?

Comment: How to do that? I am just running web host project.

Comment: Google it.  The dev web server typically only accepts local requests by default

Comment: if your mac is in the same network, try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Comment: @RyanMotal tried this, not working on any device. I did follow the steps and added inbound rule on api server machine

Comment: @RyanMotal after trying different addresses, restarting and reading conveyor log I got to know that setting localhost:port was causing exception so I used 127.0.0.1 and it worked for one adddress. If you post this as answer , I will upvote and accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Mac is in the Same network as your device running the local Server and, Install this Tool [Conveyor by Keyoti](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti)